# Differential amplifier circuit does not work at small voltages

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier

I am using an op-amp as a differential amplifier to find the current draw of a load by measuring the voltage across a 0.1 Ω resistor that the current goes through. I set it up using this schematic:

[image: diff-amp circuit]

R1 and R2 are 1.1 kΩ and R3 and R4 are 10 kΩ for a 10× gain. There is a 0.1 Ω resistor between V1 and V2, the load is connected to V1 and operates at 12 V, pulling a range of 370 mA to 3 A. I am using an [OP177](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP177.pdf), powered off +24 V.

For the most part the circuit works across the range I need it to: from a V<sub>diff</sub> of 90-290 mV, V<sub>out</sub> is 0.88-2.94 V. However, any V<sub>diff</sub> under ~90 mV results in the same V<sub>out</sub> of 0.83 V. It seems like the op-amp has a certain voltage differential threshold between V1 and V2 required to operate correctly, but I cannot find anything in the datasheet that talks about this.

Can someone verify that this is an actual spec rather than something I did wrong in my circuit, and if so, how do I find this value in the datasheet?

Comment: Nope, not an "actual spec".  What's the tolerance on your resistors?  Can you show a picture of your layout? What's the amplifier driving? Have you looked at the output with a scope?

Comment: How are you powering your op amp, and what op amp is it??  It may not be capable of going under 0.83V

Comment: @JohnD The 0.1ohm is 1%, the other four are basic breadboard guys so probably 5% or 10%. I attribute the tolerance on the gain value to that, but don't see how the tolerances would cause this. I can't show you the physical testing layout. The amplifier is not driving anything, I'm using it as a current sensing device. The scope shows the output as a slightly noisy 0.83V.

Comment: @ScottSeidman It is an OP177 as shown in the question. Unusual input stage topology and unusually low offset voltage specs and pretty low offset/bias current, too.

Comment: @InBedded16 If the resistor values are not tightly matched the common-mode rejection will be poor, and the output will pass some of the DC common mode voltage at the input.  If I recall correctly 1% resistors will result in a CMRR of around 48dB, but 5 or 10 % resistors will be way worse.  There's also the issue of the part not being rail-to-rail output, so if your supplies are not bipolar you can run into the output swing limitation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OP177 isn't a rail-to-rail op amp. The datasheet specifies behaviour at ±15 V power, and all it guarantees is that it will get within 1.5 V of the rails (saturating at ±13.5 V) if the output load is light enough.

[image]

So getting 0.83 V output when the negative rail is 0 V is actually a decent amount better than the specifications would imply.

Comment: Why on Earth would anyone use a precision device like this without a bipolar supply? But I see the 24 V and I don't see the questioner mentioning that this is +/- 12 V. Hopefully, they will say they are using +/- 12 V?

Comment: @periblepsis I've seen enough people do that to suspect, at least.

Comment: @periblepsis nope, using +24V. I honestly don't have a ton of experience working with negative voltages, definitely a topic to brush up on. But it seems to me that this works just fine the way I'm doing it, why is this "bad"?

Comment: @Hearth so basically, it outlines power supply at +- 15V, and output voltage range at +-14V (depending on RL). So you can surmise that the output voltage can only get to within 1V of the rail, and possibly better depending on certain conditions which I must have luckily created in my circuit? Do I have that right?

Comment: @InBedded16 If you don't understand why that's "bad" look at the specs more carefully.  The output can't get to 0V in your case, or whatever the negative rail is, so it will saturate somewhere above that.

Comment: @JohnD oh duh. Because if I use a bipolar power supply, a 0.50mV differential for example would be well above the negative rail, and thus valid. But its only "bad" because I want to sense voltages near 0V - if I cared about 2-5V for example, it would be just fine.

Comment: @InBedded16 I would say the reason it's better isn't just due to circuit conditions (though it is partially; it'd probably be very different at extreme temperatures, for instance), but also just that the individual chip you have could be better than the rating. The ratings only have a minimum and a typical--they guarantee that the device will be no *worse* than that, but not that it won't be better. They want it to be better, in fact, to have a margin of error so you don't come to them with lawyers and claim they didn't meet the guaranteed performance!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are running the operational amplifier from a single supply of +24V (VDD=24V, VSS=0V)

Op-Amps have a range of allowable input voltages that it can work at for normal operation in a linear manor. This is often called the input common mode voltage.

In the differential Op-Amp circuit above, I am assuming that V2 is also grounded and so V- is sitting at or close to 0V. In order to handle inputs so close to either supply rail (in this case VSS), you need a rail to rail input Op-Amp, which the OP177 is not.

The OP177 has an input voltage range (Table 1, OP177 datasheet) of +/-14V (Typ) for a +/-15V supply. In other words, the Op-Amp inputs need to be +/-1V above the rail for the Op-Amp to work reliably. This is a typical case, minimum is +/-13V.

Coming back to your circuit, I suspect that there is some additional parasitic resistance between V2 and Ground. At higher currents flowing through the 0.1R measurement resistor, V2 rises just enough for the op-amp to work as expected. At lower measurement currents, V2 is too close to the VSS negative rail, and so   V+ is too close to the VSS negative rail, so the Op-Amp doesn't work as expected.